# viewport, site width and iPad

Tags: css, ipad, viewport

I have a temp site here : http://studioteknik.co/solertia.ca/equipe-rh/
the template site have been design for 1092 px, on a large monitor everything breath, everything fine. But on my iPad that is 1024px, all the text at the left is right next to the screen... no space it's ugly.

What i like is to tell the viewport to look like a 1200px monitor and whot it off accordigy..

if i say : `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200">` it does not do ANYTHING at all... everything look as crappy !

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're building a responsive website, then the following meta tag is standard in packages such as Twitter's [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Also, if you want to add extra styles such as padding to your website on small screens, you can use CSS media queries like so:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

.content {
padding: 0 20px;
}

}
```

This would stop your content touching the edges of your screen.

Common responsive breakpoints are [explained here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: What i try to make is not to compensate at different screen size, it's to make a 1024 screen look like a 200px wide (so i think it will scale ?)